# How to use EC2 instance role wht Aws Cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I run aws command like `aws s3 ls`, it uses default profile. Can I create a new profile to use a role attached to EC2 instance?
If so, how can I write credentials/config files?

Comment: Is there any reason you have a credentials file on your EC2 with a role? :)

Comment: Credentials are used by operators and in some operations, we need EC2 role authorization...

Comment: The attached role needed "sts:AssumeRole" action permission. 1)Add the privilege to the role. 2) edit ~/.aws/cofig "[profile some_profile_name]\ncredential_source = Ec2InstanceMetadata" Then, aws command like "aws s3 ls --profile some_profile_name" does what we need.

Answer (score 5):

From [Credentials — Boto 3 Docs documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/guide/configuration.html):

> The mechanism in which boto3 looks for credentials is to search through a list of possible locations and stop as soon as it finds credentials. The order in which Boto3 searches for credentials is:
>
> 1. Passing credentials as parameters in the `boto.client()` method
> 2. Passing credentials as parameters when creating a `Session` object
> 3. Environment variables
> 4. **Shared credential file** (`~/.aws/credentials`)
> 5. AWS config file (`~/.aws/config`)
> 6. Assume Role provider
> 7. Boto2 config file (`/etc/boto.cfg` and `~/.boto`)
> 8. **Instance metadata service** on an Amazon EC2 instance that has an IAM role configured.

Since the *Shared Credential File* is consulted before the *Instance Metadata service*, it is *not* possible to use an assigned IAM Role if a credentials file is provided.

**One idea to try:** You could **create another user on the EC2 instance** that does *not* have a credentials file in their `~/.aws/` directory. In this case, later methods will be used. I haven't tried it, but using `sudo su` might be sufficient to change to this other user and use the IAM Role.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if you have a credentials file, use the [environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html) or specify the IAM key/IAM secret via the SDK these will always take a higher precedence than the using the role itself.

If the credentials are required infrequently you could create another role that the EC2s IAM role can assume (using [sts:AssumeRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html)) whenever it needs to perform these interactions. You would then remove the credentials file on disk.

**If you must** have a credentials file on the disk, the suggestion would be to **create another user** on the server exclusively for using these credentials. As a credentials file is only used by default for that user all other users will not use this file (unless explicitly stated within the SDK/CLI interaction as an argument).

Ensure that your local user that you create is locked down as much a possible to reduce the chance of unauthorized users gaining access to the user and its credentials.

Answer (score 0):

This is what we solved this problem.I write this answer in case this is valuable for other people looking for answer.

1. Add a role "some-role" to a instance with id "i-xxxxxx"

```
$ aws iam create-instance-profile --instance-profile-name some-profile-name
$ aws iam add-role-to-instance-profile --instance-profile-name some-profile-name --role-name some_role
$ aws ec2 associate-iam-instance-profile --iam-instance-profile Name=some-profile-name --instance-id i-xxxxxx
```

2. Attach "sts:AssumeRole"

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "sts:AssumeRole"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
$ aws iam update-assume-role-policy --role-name some-role --policy-document file://policy.json
```

3. Define profile in the instance
   Add "some-operator-profile" to use EC2 instace role.
   ~/.aws/config

```
[profile some-operator-profile]
credential_source = Ec2InstanceMetadata
```

4. Do what you want with the EC2 provided role

```
$ aws --profile some-operator-profile s3 ls
```